# Is reading a property from an assignment expression UB in C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I have the following code snippet:

```
_nhp_array_char_t intpd_str1; 
intpd_str1.length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "You\'re %.*s!", (_nhp_var_str = _nhp_var_you->to_array_char->_nhp_this_anon(_nhp_var_you->to_array_char)).length, _nhp_var_str.buffer);
intpd_str1.buffer = _nhp_malloc(intpd_str1.length + 1); 
intpd_str1.responsible_destroyer = NULL; 
snprintf(intpd_str1.buffer, intpd_str1.length + 1, "You\'re %.*s!", _nhp_var_str.length, _nhp_var_str.buffer);
```

Calling `_nhp_var_you->to_array_char->_nhp_this_anon(_nhp_var_you->to_array_char)` should, and does, return a struct with `length` 22, and a valid value for `buffer`.

The expression `intpd_str1.length = snprintf...` evaluates to 14, however. However, in GDB, running the assignment expression beforehand, then reading `_nhp_var_str.length` returns the correct value of 30.

I suspect that there must be some form of undefined-behavior, though I haven't been able to confirm it, even after searching google and SO. I think, for some reason, when evaluating `(_nhp_var_str = _nhp_var_you->to_array_char->_nhp_this_anon(_nhp_var_you->to_array_char)).length`, it decides to produce the result of `_nhp_var_str.length` instead without assigning a value to `_nhp_var_str`.

FYI, the code looks messy because it's transpiled; as far as coding style goes, there's not much I can do to actually change it.

Comment: The evaluation of function call arguments is unsequenced.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to ensure the evaluations are sequenced? @EricPostpischil

Comment: @EricPostpischil Does that mean, `fn(a, b, c)` it's not given that `a` will be evaluated before `b` etc.?

Comment: @marco-a: It not only means there is no guarantee that `a` will be evaluated before `b`, there is no guarantee that “`a` will be evaluated before `b` or `b` will be evaluated before `a`.” The C implementation could evaluate parts of `a` intermixed with parts of `b`. Even if the expressions look like single operations to a naïve C program, such as `x = 3` or `++x`, the C implementation could implement these as compound operations such as updating the individual bytes of `x` in separate operations, and it can be doing different parts of those from `a` and `b` in a mix.

Comment: @mike: The behavior of that code is fundamentally not defined by the C standard. You need to make it generate other code, or perhaps you can apply some postprocessing to fix the generated code. You should also report the bug to the author of the transpiler.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So you want to say `fn(a, b, c)` the order is completely undefined (it could be `a->b->c` but could also be `a->c->b`, `b->c->a` etc.) right? Wow.. I didn't know that :)

Comment: @marco-a No, it's even worse. There can be no order. `f(a + b + c, d + e)` can calculate `a + b` first, then `d + e`, then add `c` to the first result, and finally call `f`.

Comment: @marco-a: The order can not only be a→b or b→a, it could be a part 1→b part 2→a part 2→b part 3→b part 1→a part 3 or infinitely many other orders.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How come you're so intimate with the C specification. Is it experience? Is it from books? Is it from having to work with the C standard itself :D sorry, I'm just curious how one would go about knowing such a (important, obvious) detail.

Comment: Is `buffer` a pointer? I think it must be. If it were an array, I think this code should work. The fifth argument, `_nhp_var_str.buffer`, would not access the array; it would merely convert it to a pointer, and the value of that would not depend on the assignment to `_nhp_var_str`. And the `buffer` array would necessarily be filled before `snprintf` is called (function call arguments are of course evaluated before the function is called).

Comment: @marco-a: From answering too many questions on Stack Overflow. And studying math, including formal mathematics of computer science, and practice with language semantics and the C standard over the years, and a little interaction occasionally with compiler developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation of function call arguments is unsequenced. In `snprintf(NULL, 0, "You\'re %.*s!", (_nhp_var_str = _nhp_var_you->to_array_char->_nhp_this_anon(_nhp_var_you->to_array_char)).length, _nhp_var_str.buffer);`, the fourth and fifth arguments are:

- `(_nhp_var_str = _nhp_var_you->to_array_char->_nhp_this_anon(_nhp_var_you->to_array_char)).length`, and
- `_nhp_var_str.buffer`.

The fourth argument modifies the value of `_nhp_var_str` (as a side effect of the assignment), including its `buffer` member, and the fifth argument uses the value of `_nhp_var_str.buffer`. This violates C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

Note that the scalar object in question is `_nhp_var_str.buffer`, which I presume is a pointer, rather than the whole `_nhp_var_str` structure. (A structure is an aggregate, not a scalar.)

The behavior of the code is fundamentally not defined by the C standard. Even if we disregard 6.5 2, a C implementation may evaluate the fifth argument before it evaluates the fourth, and this results in using a value of `_nhp_var_str.buffer` before it has been set by the assignment in the fourth argument. So this output from the transpiler is broken; the transpiler is defective. Either it must be fixed or the code must be corrected after it is generated by the transpiler.